# SSAS Processing Error: The specified query is too complex to be evaluated as a single statement

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have a cube running in Analysis Services 2016 that runs a full process every night to update with the latest data. For the past few weeks, we have been getting an error that we can't figure out (xml included below). I believe the root cause of the processing failure is the error "The specified query is too complex to be evaluated as a single statement", but not sure what this means as there are only a few vague references to this error online, and not in the context of processing a cube.

The strangest thing is that the process always works when you run it manually, and it only fails some nights, other nights it works fine. There is no discernible pattern to the failures. There are a lot of partitions processing in parallel so I wonder if it is some sort of internal threading conflict in SSAS.

Can anyone give any advice on where to look to resolve this?

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/xmla-multipleresults">
    <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty">
      <Exception xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception" />
      <Messages xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception">
        <Error ErrorCode="3238658446" Description="The specified query is too complex to be evaluated as a single statement." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3239837702" Description="Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3240034325" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the indexes for the ... partition of the ... measure group of the ... cube from the ... database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3240034325" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the indexes for the ... partition of the ... measure group of the ... cube from the ... database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3240034325" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the indexes for the ... partition of the ... measure group of the ... cube from the ... database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3240034325" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the indexes for the ... partition of the ... measure group of the ... cube from the ... database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3240034325" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the indexes for the ... partition of the ... measure group of the ... cube from the ... database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
        <Error ErrorCode="3240034325" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the indexes for the ... partition of the ... measure group of the ... cube from the ... database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
      </Messages>
    </root>
  </results>
</return>
```

Comment: is the box under memory pressure? how much does the box have? how much memory is being used by other processes such as sql server?  I'll bet some task is consuming memory at the time it fails....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mitch. Its highly likely the server is under memory pressure, but I don't know the specifics. I will have a look if/when the error occurs again.

Comment: I would manually process one measure group at a time until you find which is the culprit. That error means that the SQL query was too complex. Is the SQL query using a complex view? Can you simplify the query in any way?

Comment: Or I suppose it could be a dimension SQL query which is too complex.

Comment: Hey Greg, we have done a few manual processes of the full SSAS database, but it always works fine. I wouldn't expect anything different when manually processing each measure group / dimension on their own. I would expect if a SQL query is too complex that would be a repeatable failure.

Comment: I was able to delete a bunch of old archive data, which allowed us to remove about 200 partitions, and the full cube process has been running reliably for the last week. Each of these partitions had really simple slices, so I'd guess the root cause of the issue could have been too many partition slices causing some sort of threading issue, or more likely just intense memory pressure as Mitch suggested. Thanks for the advice.